# javascript marginLeft on image onload not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, google-chrome

i have this gallery that resizes image with javascript in order to keep original aspect ratio.
about document structure : stylesheet considering this particular object is as following :

```
 #ThePicture {position:absolute;left:50%;height:100%;max-width:100%;}
```

then PHP build list of images for menu,and most recent one sets as `#ThePicture`
which is manipulated with following javascript

```
 function KeepRatio() {
 var height = document.getElementById('ThePicture').height;
 var width = document.getElementById('ThePicture').width;
 var origHeight = document.getElementById('ThePicture').naturalHeight;
 var origWidth = document.getElementById('ThePicture').naturalWidth;
 var ratio = origWidth / origHeight;
 document.getElementById('ThePicture').width = height * ratio;
 document.getElementById('ThePicture').style.marginLeft = - width/2;
 }
```

i call this function once at the instance of `window.onload` and then at every instance of selecting new image to be viewed , thus on `...ThePicture').onload`

Now the problem im having occurs only in Chrome : First there isnt any image set as ThePicture (which is almost certainly made by the Javascript function , because the initial image is in place after PHP constructed the entire page.),on FIRST click in menu to select new image , nothing happens , on SECOND click the image appears out of its intended position , and on THIRD click , the negative margin gets calculated,moving the image in its place.My page works fine in Opera and Mozilla.

Comment: please post a fiddle. By the way are you manipulating all images with one id "ThePicture" ?

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sE693/embedded/result/)  Although the fiddle doesnt reproduce the exact same bug , isnt actual link to my website more suitable ?

Comment: yes fiddle doesn't reproduce the bug......please try comment     window.Onload = KeepRatio();

Comment: did so , and no change.

Comment: i actually think problem is somewhere in getting the naturalHeight/naturalWidth , because once the images cache , bug is not present anymore